# Sorting SQL results for readability?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, database

**TO NEW VIEWERS: THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN SOLVED**

I need to change the visual layout of the SQL query results, and I CANNOT USE EXTERNAL LIBRARIES, only python/idle.

I am making a program which is supposed to take user choices and construct an SQL statement out of them which will query the database, and give the user all matching results. There is a keyword search, and the user can specify which column is being searched for the keyword. None of this worries me, I am actually stuck on something different:

My database is just one table with 9 columns, all are either chars or ints. For the purposes of testing, I have entered only three "records". In the proper database there will be somewhat over a hundred. Querying the database for example, like this:

```
select distinct label,format,catnum,year,artist,relname from testtable
```

Gives this:

```
[('PENN', 'LP', '002', '1972', 'Frank Penn', "'72"), ('GBI', 'LP', '104', '1974', 'The Mustangs', 'On Tha Rocks'), ('GBI', 'Single', '235', '1978', 'Willpower', 'Love Makes It Alright')]
```

I would be happy to know how I can output ONE RECORD PER LINE when I output the SQL query results, something like this:

```
[('PENN', 'LP', '002', '1972', 'Frank Penn', "'72"), 
('GBI', 'LP', '104', '1974', 'The Mustangs', 'On Tha Rocks'), 
('GBI', 'Single', '235', '1978', 'Willpower', 'Love Makes It Alright')]
```

Or, better still, like this, removing the speech marks and square brackets:

```
(PENN, LP, 002, 1972, Frank Penn, '72), 
(GBI, LP, 104, 1974, The Mustangs, On Tha Rocks), 
(GBI, Single, 235, 1978, Willpower, Love Makes It Alright)
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE testtable (
        label char,
        format char,
        catnum char,
        sidecat char,
        year char,
         artist char,
        relname char,
        trackname char,
        composer char,
        collection int
        )""")

conn.commit()

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("PENN", "LP", "002", "002 (B)", "1972", "Frank Penn", "'72", "The Time For Loving Is Now", "Frank Penn", 1)''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("GBI", "LP", "104", "104 (B)", "1974", "The Mustangs", "On Tha Rocks", "Someday We'll Be Together", "Unknown", 1)''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("GBI", "Single", "235", "235 (B)", "1978", "Willpower", "Love Makes It Alright", "The Mail", "Eddie Minnis", 1)''')
conn.commit()


cursor.execute("select distinct label,format,catnum,year,artist,relname from testtable")
print(cursor.fetchall())


conn.close()
```

**EDIT: This is the solution I implemented, based user nikpod's suggestion:**

```
cursor.execute("select distinct label,format,catnum,year,artist,relname from testtable")
foo = cursor.fetchall()
foo = (str(foo).replace("), ","),\n").strip('[]'))
print(foo)
conn.close()
```

Giving:

```
('PENN', 'LP', '002', '1972', 'Frank Penn', "'72"),
('GBI', 'LP', '104', '1974', 'The Mustangs', 'On Tha Rocks'),
('GBI', 'Single', '235', '1978', 'Willpower', 'Love Makes It Alright')
```

I found it's possible to use the "replace" command to remove just about everything you don't need:

```
foo = (str(foo).replace("), ","),\n").strip('[]'))
foo = (str(foo).replace("('",""))
foo = (str(foo).replace('("',""))
foo = (str(foo).replace("',",","))
foo = (str(foo).replace(", '",", "))
foo = (str(foo).replace("'),",""))
foo = (str(foo).replace("')",""))
foo = (str(foo).replace('", ',", "))
foo = (str(foo).replace(', "',", "))
foo = (str(foo).replace('"),',""))
```

Uses many lines of code, sure, but the general idea is what matters. With something like this, you can make the output a bit nicer:

```
PENN, LP, 002, 1972, Frank Penn, '72
GBI, LP, 104, 1974, The Mustangs, On Tha Rocks
GBI, Single, 235, 1978, Willpower, Love Makes It Alright
```

**Thanks to everyone for their input, originally this question was worded quite poorly**

Comment: Have you heard of using `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: Why can't you use external libraries?

Comment: Hi. Read the manual. Find out what fetchall returns. Read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have just taken a look at the ORDER BY command, I think it will be helpful to my overall program, but it does not seem relevant to this specific issue. So thanks I guess?

Comment: Your question was very lengthy, but you probably only needed 5-10 lines to get the job done.  Next time you ask, get to the point and be clear, showing us sample data.

Comment: @Ryu This piece of work is part of a school project, and one of the "goals" is that the program is easy to use by anybody, that means that it needs to run just using the basic python and libraries that come with it. It's annoying for me as well.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have seen the criticism to the layout of the question, will spend a while now editing. Thanks for feedback

Comment: @philipxy I have taken a look at this, and with some edtiting by me and others, I think now it fits the requirements. The only issue you could have with this is that I am asking for multiple answers, but it's in this manner "Can I do this? If not, then can I do this instead?"

Comment: HI. Per my last comment: What is the type of the value returned by fetchall? How does one print one of those? What restrictions are on its value? How does one get at the parts of it? What are their types? How does one print one of those? How does one get at the parts of one of those? What are their types?What restrictions are on the value of each?  How does one print one of each of those? What is are examples of printing & extracting parts from googling 'python sqlite fetchall'? How can you expect to solve this if you do not read the specification of the programs/operators you are calling?

Comment: @philipxy I don't know what you mean by value type, the database records have attributes which are chars and ints, there really isn't anything going on behind the scenes. No restrictions that I am aware of. With your mentioning of fetchall, I was able to use cursor.fetchall() in order to get nikpod's suggestion working. The sentence "What is are examples of printing & extracting parts from googling 'python sqlite fetchall'?" has left me somewhat confused.

Comment: "is are" is a typo for "are"; I meant, do the google, find examples of code calling fetchall, and find out how they print out parts of what fetchall returns. You seem to not be exerting any effort to inform yourself. So I suggest that you exert the effort to do what my other comments said, including if necessary exerting the effort to find out what my comments mean. Eg "type" is a technical term. Eg take my comments to a mentor. Eg read an intro to Python. Good luck.

Comment: @philipxy That's a fair enough categorisation, I guess I was looking for a solution without much interest in breaking it down, and understanding how it would work. I appreciate the criticism and I think this is something I should spend much more time looking into, but for now, is there any way to remove this thread? It's clear to see my question(s) were quite lazy and I doubt this will be of use to anyone in the future. The solution presented by user "nikpod" in this thread is good enough for me for now, i've been able to use "replace" to remove all unwanted brackets and speech-marks. Thanks

Comment: You can delete your own question under certain circumstances. Google 'stackexchange delete my own question'. You can't have an accepted answer. Google 'stackexchange (unaccept OR undo accept) a question'. Generally, deleting answered questions is frowned upon--someone went to some effort. Repeatedly doing than can get one banned from posting for a while--google. Best is, edit your question to be better. Read [ask] and other [help] links & the down & upvote arrow mouseover texts. And the comments. Act fast before answer upvotes. PS Congratulations on self-evaluation & self-improvement.

Comment: Looks like I can't delete this. Will edit question, and also state the solution I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print the list of tuples as a string and manipulate it as per your requirement. 
This is an example which still contains the quotes, but to your first requirement:

```
foo = [('PENN', 'LP', '002', '1972', 'Frank Penn', "'72"), ('GBI', 'LP', '104', '1974', 'The Mustangs', 'On Tha Rocks'), ('GBI', 'Single', '235', '1978', 'Willpower', 'Love Makes It Alright')]
print(str(foo).replace("), ","),\n").strip('[]'))
```

This gives the result:

```
('PENN', 'LP', '002', '1972', 'Frank Penn', "'72"),
('GBI', 'LP', '104', '1974', 'The Mustangs', 'On Tha Rocks'),
('GBI', 'Single', '235', '1978', 'Willpower', 'Love Makes It Alright')
```

Comment: Hi nikpod, thanks for your reply. This would fit the bill somewhat, but I cannot get it to work. If I modify your code to store the query results as a variable, instead of the list itself (this is necessary) it looks like this: foo = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM testtable") followed by
print(str(foo).replace("), ","),\n").strip('[]')) and then my output is this: "<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02D98C60>". What to do to avoid this?

Comment: I have now successfully implemented your suggestion. It's a simple one, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you but it might.

```
example = [("index", "0", "contains", "these"),("index", "1", "contains", "these")]

list1 = example[0]  # 1st index is 0, this grabs ("index", "0", "contains", "these")
length = len(example)  # sets length to 2 for example as there are 2 lists

# you can access the elements in each list by either
example[0][1]  # gives "1"

# or the same thing by using list1 created earlier
list1[1]  # also gives "1"

# to work through all lists and all elements in the list
for each_list in example:
    # do something at the start of a list
    for each_element in each_list:
        print(each_element)
        # do something to each element in a list
    # do something at the end of a list
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, I am sure that this can be used, although in a slightly different context. Perhaps in queries where only one result is displayed. Thanks for the contribution.